# Object Arrays map values inside for/foreach loop to print the JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

This object contains --> array --> object. Using for/foreach or another method I need to iterate the ROW in the table. This is React JSX code. Could someone please help me understand what to do?

```
a:{
 bb: [{}],
 cc: [{}],
 dd: [{}]
}
```

**I need to iterate object "a" using dynamic "key" and render JSX Row code in a Table using attribute in side the nested objects.**

```
render() {
    const {
      data: {
        drivers: { user, month, year, createdAt },
      },
    } = this.props;

let DriverCommissionResults = {};
let recent = "";
let combinedUser = {};

DriverCommissionResults = {
   "Jane": 200,
   "Ann": 100,
   "Kevin": 50,

}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(DriverCommissionResults)) {
        combinedUser[`${key}`] = user.reduce(function (filtered, option) {
          if (option.username === key) {
            var someNewValue = {
              userId: option.userId,
              username: option.username,
              createdAt: option.createdAt,
              ranking: option.ranking,
              year: option.year,
              month: option.month,
              handle: option.handle,
              initialSalary: option.initialSalary,
              salary: option.salary,
              drunkenPesentage: option.drunkenPesentage,
              newTotalCommission: value,
            };
            filtered.push(someNewValue);
          }
          return filtered;
        }, []);
      }

      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(DriverCommissionResults)) {
        recent = combinedUser[`${key}`].map((filteredPerson) => (
          <RowComponent
            newSalary={filteredPerson.initialSalary}
            key={filteredPerson.userId}
            member={filteredPerson}
            card={cardMode}
            newTotalCommission={filteredPerson.newTotalCommission}
          />
        ));
      }

return (
  <Fragment>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Handle</th>
          <th>InitialSalary</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{recent}</tbody>
    </table>
  </Fragment>
}
```

```
console.log(combinedUser);

{Jane: Array(1), Ann: Array(1), Kevin: Array(1)}

{
Jane: [{handle: "Jane", username: "Jane", salary: 40000, initialSalary: 40100, }],
Ann: [{handle: "Ann", username: "Ann", salary: 50000, initialSalary: 50100,}],
Kevin: [{handle: "Kevin", username: "Kevin", salary: 30000, initialSalary: 30100,}],
}
```

*Output*

**Handle    InitialSalary    Salary**

Kevin        30000            30100

> **Expected Output**

**Handle    InitialSalary    Salary**

Jane         40000            40100

Ann          50000            50100

Kevin        30000            30100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `recent` got overwritten inside the `for` loop.
Try this out

```
const recent = []
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(DriverCommissionResults)) {
    combinedUser[`${key}`].forEach((filteredPerson) => (
      recent.push(<RowComponent
            newSalary={filteredPerson.initialSalary}
            key={filteredPerson.userId}
            member={filteredPerson}
            card={cardMode}
            newTotalCommission={filteredPerson.newTotalCommission}
         />);
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build items like below and use it in render.

```
const obj = {
  Jane: [
    { handle: "Jane", username: "Jane", salary: 40000, initialSalary: 40100 },
  ],
  Ann: [
    { handle: "Ann", username: "Ann", salary: 50000, initialSalary: 50100 },
  ],
  Kevin: [
    { handle: "Kevin", username: "Kevin", salary: 30000, initialSalary: 30100 },
  ],
};

const items = Object.values(obj).map(([rowObj]) => {
  return (
    <div key={rowObj.handle}>
      {Object.entries(rowObj)
        .filter(([key]) =>
          ["username", "salary", "initialSalary"].includes(key)
        )
        .map(([key, value]) => (
          <div key={key}> {value} </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```